# How to pass env parameter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to update the @test:registry = value to the myNode.js process that it called from package.json
I tried to update all the env but it didn't work.
Is it possible to do it from childproc.execSync ?

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test1",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "node myNode.js",
        "start": "node node_modules/xx"
    }
}
```

myNode.js

```
childproc.execSync('npm install && npm run build', { cwd: '..', shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' , env : {env:process.env}})
```

I tried also

```
  childproc.execSync('npm install && npm run build', { cwd: '..', shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' , env : {env:{ 'npm_config__test_registry':value}})
```

then I got /bin/sh: 1: npm: not foundchild_process.js:644    throw err;    ^

I tried to print the process.env before I created the childproc and then I saw my relevant settings but when I tried to check it in the childProc with npm config list I saw different values

when I tried

```
childproc.execSync('npm config set @test:registry:value && npm install && npm run build', { cwd: '..', shell: true, stdio: 'inherit'  })
```

then it worked . is it possible to do it with the env in the execSync

Answer (score 0):

Add in `myNode.js`

You can set your environment varibale in `process.env`

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

Comment: where do I need to set it ? and How I can update the @scope registry ?

Comment: but I open new process in the childProc so How I can move the process.env to the chidlproc ?

Comment: I tried to do console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); and I got undefined

Comment: You can set here env variable using that

Comment: when I console.log(process.env) I got the list of the npm_config but when I tried to do npm config list from the childProc I didn't see the same configuration

Comment: what do I need to pass in process.env.NODE_ENV ? I tried to pass all the env and it didn't work

Comment: process.env.npm_config__test_registry = value

Comment: process.env.npm_config__test_registry already had this value the problem is in the process that was created childproc it has a wrong env and I tried to set it but it didn't work

Comment: if I will do  childproc.execSync('npm config set @test:registry ' + process.env.npm_config__test_registry + ' && npm install && npm run build', { cwd: '..', shell: true, stdio: 'inherit'  }) then it worked can I do it in diffrerent way without the npm config  and somehow pass the env to the childproc